# jQuery Show php GET variable value in a textarea dynamically

Tags: php, jquery

Im trying to show `GET` variable data in a `textarea`. I tried may solutions in StackOverflow but none of them worked. I have no idea why. Can you please tell me if I'm missing something.

**My Story**

I have a link on a page and `href` is `/index.php?page=contact-us&performance=Lamborghini`

and it takes me to the Contact Us page and the url is still `/index.php?page=contact-us&performance=Lamborghini` which is what I want.

So, Im tyring to grab `performance` variables's content which is **Lamborghini** and print it in a `textarea` which is

```
<textarea name="m62b34fbrp__32" cols="19" rows="7" class="cms_textarea" id="fbrp__32"></textarea>
```

So what I did is added `<?php $performanceInfo= $_GET['performance']; ?>` to the top of my page. Then added `$("#fbrp__32").val(<?php echo $performanceInfo; ?>);` in my `script.js` file. But it never prints Lamborghini in the `textarea`.

When I try `$("#fbrp__32").val('<?php echo $performanceInfo; ?>');` (Notice the `'` marks) it prints `<?php echo $performanceInfo; ?>` in the `textarea`.

When I `<?php echo $_GET["performance"]; ?>` it prints **Lamborghini** fine too.

Can you guys tell me why its not working for me?

NOTE : I cant edit the `textarea` manually as it is generated using a `plugin` Thanks a lot.

Comment: inside `js` or `php` file ?

Comment: do you only have a .php file or do you also have a .js file?

Comment: I have both. PHP file and a .js file which is `script.js` included into the PHP file

Comment: @Jashwant he said `script.js` see my response below.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Parse will not parse `.js` files, you will need to do this outside of the `.js` file. If not you will need to in your webserver config file set to parse `.js` files as PHP files.

**EDIT**

You mentioned that you added `<?php $performanceInfo= $_GET['performance']; ?>` to the top of the page and then `$("#fbrp__32").val(<?php echo $performanceInfo; ?>);` to your `script.js` file. This will not work as per default configuration `script.js` or any `.js` file will not be interpreted by the PHP parser. so your statement `$("#fbrp__32").val(<?php echo $performanceInfo; ?>);` will cause a syntax error.

The best way to handle it without changing server configuration would be to do this at the top of your page.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  var performance = "<?php echo $_GET['performance']; ?>";
  </script>
```

and in your `script.js` file do `$("#fbrp__32").val(performance);`

Comment: @francisco.preller read it again, he says `Then added $("#fbrp__32").val(<?php echo $performanceInfo; ?>); in my script.js file. But it never prints Lamborghini in the textarea.`

Comment: yes, I did re-read, I suspect you are correct and OP is using two files. My apologies! :)

Comment: @DevZer0 sorry can you please clarify what I have to do? I was looking this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5895840/1889007) and it says you can assign a 'php' value to `js`? Im confused

Comment: @DevZer0 thanks. But it still prints `<?php echo $_GET['performance']; ?>` in my textarea

Comment: You say when you do `When I <?php echo $_GET["performance"]; ?> it prints Lamborghini fine too.` Then there should be nothing preventing it from setting the word Lamborghini to the java script vaiable

Comment: @DevZer0 yeha its weird. This never happened to me before. Anyway see below for my solution that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<textarea name="m62b34fbrp__32" cols="19" rows="7" class="cms_textarea" id="fbrp__32">

<?php echo $_REQUEST['performance']; ?></textarea>
```

OR in JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var performance='<?php echo $_REQUEST["performance"]; ?>';
 $("#fbrp__32").val(performance);
 });
```

Comment: JS solution prints `<?php echo $_REQUEST["performance"]; ?>` and I cant edit the textarea to put `<?php echo $_REQUEST['performance']; ?>` in it. :(

Comment: what about this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url

Comment: Never inject unsanitized, unescaped data into the page!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following right before the textarea (in your PHP/HTML-file, not JS-File!):

```
var performance = <?php echo '"' . htmlspecialchars( $_GET['performance'] ) . '"'; ?>
$("#fbrp__32").val(performance);
```

Comment: Never inject unsanitized, unescaped data into the page!

Answer (score 0):

Just set value directly using PHP

```
<?php
 $performanceInfo= $_GET['performance']; 
?>
```

JQuery is a bit tricky.Instead try simple javascript for setting value:

```
document.getElementById("Enter Here Textarea Id").value = <?PHP echo $_GET['performance']; ?>
```

Comment: Did you import JQuery library(.js file) for using JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally this is the solution which worked for me.

In the php file I put

```
<?php

$performanceInfo= $_GET['performance'];
echo "<script>";
echo "$('#fbrp__32').val('$performanceInfo');";
echo "</script>";

?>
```

Its weird other solutions didnt work for me for somereason.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var value = <?php $performanceInfo= $_GET['performance']; ?>
    $("#fbrp__32").val(value);
```

NB: php tags will not not render in js files

Comment: @user1889007 try this. It will work if the code is in a html file. Hope you are not using a js file

Comment: iirc, val will input into textarea anyway

Comment: The `val()` method sets the `value` property, not the `value` attribute. It is the correct way to change the value of a textarea programatically. Also: Never inject unsanitized, unescaped data into the page!